# Is there any API to get the Date wise likes,comments,shares count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any API to get the following data.

1. Date wise likes,comments,shares count
2. Likes count based on age,gender
3. Recent Notifications
4. Messages of page(page Inbox)

I have tried for couple of days but no luck. Could anyone please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really a technical problem? Please could you re-phrase it as a technical question?

Comment: @Jon Story ,I have just edit my question could you please review.

Comment: That's a much better question, although still a little vague. Unfortunately I don't know the answer, but hopefully someone will come along who does.

Answer (score -1):

By using this graph uri, you will get likes, comment, share count of the each post for the particular date:

```
{Page-id}/feed?fields=id,created_time,shares,comments.limit(1).summary(true),reactions.limit(1).summary(true)&since=2018-01-11&until=2018-01-12
```